# Render Multiple Partial View from Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3, in which I have a page let say Home.cshtml with `<Ul></Ul>` tag. Now I have 5 Partial View with `li` and some html. Partial view are based on permission, I have this code in my controller.

```
List<IPermissionEntity> list => This return me list of permission.id of that user.
```

From DataBase I got Id, PartialView Name.

Now how can I call Partial View if permission.id = 1 then a particular partial view render.
If permission to view two or three partial Views then how can i see them. I am trying with foreach loop and taken PartialView Name and trying to putting in @Url but still I am stuck for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To render partial views, I think you want @Html.Partial, not @Url:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var permissionEntity in permissionEntities)
{
    Html.Partial(permissionEntity.PartialViewName)
}
</ul>
```